# Unable to install GSIF package in R

Tags: r

I am trying to install the GSIF package via the following code:

```
install.packages("GSIF", repos=c("http://R-Forge.R-project.org"), type="source", dependencies=TRUE)
```

The following error message appears

```
Warning in install.packages :
  dependencies ‘soiltexture’, ‘quantregForest’, ‘AICcmodavg’, ‘SDMTools’, ‘maxlike’ are not available
trying URL 'http://R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib/GSIF_0.5-5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1815922 bytes (1.7 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.7 MB

* installing *source* package ‘GSIF’ ...
** using staged installation
** R
** data
** demo
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in setMethod("describe", signature(x = "WPS"), function(x, request = "describeprocess",  : 
  no existing definition for function ‘describe’
Error: unable to load R code in package ‘GSIF’
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘GSIF’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/GSIF’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘GSIF’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/4c/ftr4g6ds49107z8jy593rwbc0000gn/T/Rtmpq5RWmw/downloaded_packages’
```

I run R 4.1.2 Bird Hippie on macOS Big Sur 11.6

Any advice?

Thanks in advance,
Jan

Comment: It looks as if all the pakages that the error message complains about are available on CRAN.  Try installing them first with `install.packages()`, without the `repos=` parameter.

Comment: It looks like some package used to define a generic function named `describe` that this package was trying to create a custom method before. But the generic function doesn't exist any more. It doesn't appear that the `GSIF` package has been updated in 3 years and it was [removed from CRAN for non-compliance](https://cran.r-project.org/package=GSIF). It's unlikely to work without a bunch of fixes.

Comment: @jiklein did you succeed in this installation? I am facing this same issue for 2days now

Comment: @NgesBrian I did not succeed in installing the package. I have downloaded the package and manually loaded the R functions. You can find it on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/GSIF/). Make sure to load source("AAAA.R") before loading other functions and closing with source("ZZZ.R")

Comment: @jlklein thank you for the comment. I have tried that but it's not working. I need to load soil data and get properties of a particular coordinate. I am new to this area

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

1. Download the "GSIF_0.5-5.1.zip" from this website: https://cran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2020-04-20/web/packages/GSIF/index.html
2. Go to the RStudio console and type:

```
install.packages("C:/Users/.../Downloads/GSIF_0.5-5.1.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")
```

Comment: @jlklein is on a Mac

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring because the generic constructor for the S4 method `"describe"` isn't being created. I have no idea why; the code contains the file `AAAA.R` (which is sourced [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441038/changing-the-load-order-of-files-in-an-r-package) in the package) with a perfectly sensible constructor in it:

```
if(!isGeneric("describe")){
setGeneric("describe", function(x, ...){standardGeneric("describe")})
}
```

For whatever reason, this test is failing -- i.e. `"describe"` *is* a generic -- and so the way to get it to install cleanly is -- and insert giant "I have no idea if this is actually a good idea" warning here --

1. Download the archive from CRAN
2. Untar / gz
3. Above line 31 of `R/wpsworldgrids.R`, which defines the method, add the line for the constructor:
   `setGeneric("describe", function(x, ...){standardGeneric("describe")})`
4. Run `devtools::install('/path/to/your/folder/GSIF')` to install it
5. Pray that this hasn't cocked anything clever up I do not understand...

Note that the methods in GDAL this is based on are themselves due to become "end of life" soon:

```
> library('GSIF')
The legacy packages maptools, rgdal, and rgeos, underpinning this package
will retire shortly. Please refer to R-spatial evolution reports on
https://r-spatial.org/r/2023/05/15/evolution4.html for details.
This package is now running under evolution status 0
Please note that rgdal will be retired during October 2023,
plan transition to sf/stars/terra functions using GDAL and PROJ
at your earliest convenience.
See https://r-spatial.org/r/2023/05/15/evolution4.html and https://github.com/r-spatial/evolution
rgdal: version: 1.6-7, (SVN revision 1203)
Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 3.4.1, released 2021/12/27
Path to GDAL shared files: /usr/share/gdal
GDAL binary built with GEOS: TRUE
Loaded PROJ runtime: Rel. 8.2.1, January 1st, 2022, [PJ_VERSION: 821]
Path to PROJ shared files: /home/jackmiller/.local/share/proj:/usr/share/proj
PROJ CDN enabled: FALSE
Linking to sp version:1.6-1
To mute warnings of possible GDAL/OSR exportToProj4() degradation,
use options("rgdal_show_exportToProj4_warnings"="none") before loading sp or rgdal.
GSIF version 0.5-5.1 (2019-01-04)
URL: http://gsif.r-forge.r-project.org/
```

Answer (score -1):

1. first, install `devtools` R package by running install.packages("devtools")`
2. download the source code of `GSIF` package from https://cran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2020-04-20/src/contrib/GSIF_0.5-5.1.tar.gz
3. then install the `GSIF` package as follows:
   `devtools::install_local("~/Downloads/GSIF_0.5-5.1.tar.gz")`

Note: make sure to give the proper path to the compressed `GSIF` package file based on your system. If you get error like `ERROR: dependencies ‘RSAGA’, ‘dismo’, ‘rgdal’, ‘raster’, ‘plotKML’ are not available for package ‘GSIF’` then download (from CRAN) and install each of these packages from source as described in the steps 2 and 3 above.

Comment: All dependencies are correctly installed. When executing the steps above, the same error message appears:

Error in setMethod("describe", signature(x = "WPS"), function(x, request = "describeprocess",  : 
  no existing definition for function ‘describe’
Error: unable to load R code in package ‘GSIF’
Execution halted