# R GSIF package buffer.dist(): 'subscript out of bounds'

Tags: r

I which to use the buffer.dist() function of the GSIF package developed by Tomislav Hengl et al. (2018). It  has not been updated since 2019 and was [taken down from CRAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73559636/unable-to-install-gsif-package-in-r).

According to the authors, the buffer.dist() function derives gridded maps of Euclidean distances for each individual sampling point in form of a RasterBrick. These are to be used as spatial covariates in the randomforest model to account for spatial autocorrelation in the prediction. I unfortunately cannot exactly tell how the final result looks like for the GSIF package is no longer available.

I downloaded the latest version of GSIF (v0.5-5 - 2019-01-04) from the [CRAN repository](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/GSIF/) and loaded the functions manually into the R workspace. All functions can be found in the folder "R".

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.6
```

```
# Manually load GSIF environment (manually download from CRAN repository)
source("AAAA.R") # needs to be loaded first
# Manually load function buffer.dist()
source("buffer.dist.R")

# Load library
library(sp)
library(plotKML)
library(raster)
library(gstat)

## Follow the workflow in the tutorial: https://peerj.com/articles/5518/GeoMLA_README_thengl.pdf
# Load example data from gstat package
data(meuse, echo = FALSE)
data(meuse.grid)

# transform into SpatialPoints objects (input data requirement for buffer.dist() )
meuse.sp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(meuse[1:2], meuse[3:14], proj4string = CRS('+init=epsg:4326'))
meuse.grid.spdf <- SpatialPixelsDataFrame(meuse.grid[1:2], meuse.grid[6], proj4string = CRS('+init=epsg:4326'))

# derive buffer distances for each individual point, using the buffer function in the raster package which derives a gridded map for each observation point ()
grid.dist0 <- buffer.dist(meuse.sp["zinc"], 
                          meuse.grid.spdf[1],
                          as.factor(1:nrow(meuse.sp)))
```

This gives me the following error message:

> Error in x@coords[i, , drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds

Here is the buffer.dist() function (Hengl et al., 2018):

```
setMethod("buffer.dist", signature(observations = "SpatialPointsDataFrame", predictionDomain = "SpatialPixelsDataFrame"), function(observations, predictionDomain, classes, width, ...){
  if(missing(width)){ width <- sqrt(areaSpatialGrid(predictionDomain)) }
  if(!length(classes)==length(observations)){ stop("Length of 'observations' and 'classes' does not match.") }
  ## remove classes without any points:
  xg = summary(classes, maxsum=length(levels(classes)))
  selg.levs = attr(xg, "names")[xg > 0]
  if(length(selg.levs)<length(levels(classes))){
    fclasses <- as.factor(classes)
    fclasses[which(!fclasses %in% selg.levs)] <- NA
    classes <- droplevels(fclasses)
  }
  ## derive buffer distances
  s <- list(NULL)
  for(i in 1:length(levels(classes))){
    s[[i]] <- raster::distance(rasterize(observations[which(classes==levels(classes)[i]),1]@coords, y=raster(predictionDomain)), width=width, ...)
  }
  s <- s[sapply(s, function(x){!is.null(x)})]
  s <- brick(s)
  s <- as(s, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")
  s <- s[predictionDomain@grid.index,]
  return(s)
})
```

I went through all steps of the function manually. It is in the second last row where the bug seems to occur:

> s <- s[predictionDomain@grid.index,]
> Error in x@coords[i, , drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds

Do you have any suggestion how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You do not describe what that method does, but it seems that it does something like this:

```
bufdist <- function(obs, r, classes, width) {
    s <- list()
    cls <- sort(unique(classes))
    for (i in 1:length(cls)) {
        obsi <- obs[classes==cls[i], ]
        x <- rasterize(obsi, r)
        s[[i]] <- buffer(x, width, background=NA)
    }
    names(s) <- cls
    rast(s)
}

library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)
set.seed(1)
v <- spatSample(r, 50, as.points=TRUE)
cls <- sample(LETTERS[1:4], 50, replace=TRUE)
b <- bufdist(v, r, cls, 7500)


plot(b, col="red")
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I just recently got back to the issue. I added a description of what the function does in my post. I do not quite comprehend what your function outputs, as it produces four maps, could you maybe elaborate?